# Relationship of columns of an array with respective values

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have an array filled by a push with values ​​from another array, which forms the `parameters` array, in this array the even indices (0,2,4 ..) represent the titles, and in the odd indices (1,3,5. .) represent the values ​​for each title (label1,2,3,4 ...), the values ​​contained in this label array can be greater than 2, as in the example below, it can contain up to 5 or more values. I would like to relate the values ​​of the labels with the titles to upload this data in a database and generate metrics, any suggestions?

*Code snippet:*

```
    const content = await rawResponse.json();

    var parameters = [];
    var data = Object.keys(content);
    var squads = Object.keys(content[data]);
    var cards = Object.keys(content[data][squads][0]["cards"]);

    try {

        for (x in cards) {

            const row = content[data][squads][0]["cards"][x];

            const labels = [

                (row['primaryLabels'] || ""),
                (row['secondaryLabel'] || "")

            ]

            parameters.push(labels[0], [row['title']]);

        }

            var col = 0;
            var row = 0;

            while(row < parameters[col].length){
                console.info(parameters[col][row]);
                row ++;
            }

    } catch (err) {

        console.error(`Error Array - ${err}`);

    }
```

*Parameters (array):*

```
  [
    'label1',
    'label2'
  ],
  [ 'Title - 001' ],
  [ 'label1', 
    'label3'
  ],
  [ 'Title - 002' ],
  [
    'label1',
    'label4'
  ],
  [ 'Title - 004' ],
  ... And so on
```

*Output const labels:*

```
[ 'label1', 'label2' ]
[ 'label1', 'label3' ]
... And so on
```

*Output code:*

```
label1
label2
```

*Desired Output:*

```
|-------------------------------|
| column-title | val1   | val2  |
|-------------|--------|--------|
| Title - 001 | label1 | label2 |
|-------------|--------|--------|
| Title - 002 | label1 | label3 |
|-------------------------------|
... And so on
```

Comment: please add an example of the complete data and the wanted result of it.

Comment: The data output is very large, the desired output is at the desired output

Comment: I made a mistake in writing for the desired output, corrected, sorry!

Comment: The parameters array, will always follow the pattern of the example Parameters (Array)

Comment: then take a subset with three or four items.

Comment: See if it improved, pelase!

Comment: can you add a real javascript data structure, not only parts. it is unclear, waht you are doing with the parts ans where they are coming from.

Comment: done, check, please!